# MultiIndex from lists of lists with irregular length

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a list of lists that I would like to make into a multi-index pandas dataframe that I can then merge to an original pandas dataframe. Each row of the list consists of an observation and the values in the lists consists of corresponding rows that match that observation.

Here is a simple version of what I have:

The original dataframe is of the following form:

```
original=(pd.DataFrame([['JFK','New York, NY'],['EWR','Newark, NJ'],
                        ['BWI','Baltimore, MD'],['PHL','Philadelphia, PA'],
                        ['DCA','Washington, DC']],columns=['ID','City']))
original
    ID              City
0  JFK      New York, NY
1  EWR        Newark, NJ
2  BWI     Baltimore, MD
3  PHL  Philadelphia, PA
4  DCA    Washington, DC
```

The matching output (which matches locations to other locations within a certain radius) is a list of lists as follows:

```
matches=[[0],[1,3],[2],[1,3],[4]]
matches
[[0], [1, 3], [2], [1, 3], [4]]
```

Here is what I would like it to look like:

```
              ID              City
Org Match
0   0        JFK      New York, NY
1   1        EWR        Newark, NJ 
    3        PHL  Philadelphia, PA 
2   2        BWI     Baltimore, MD
3   1        EWR        Newark, NJ
    3        PHL  Philadelphia, PA
4   4        DCA    Washington, DC
```

I know how to join on the multi-index levels, but cannot figure out how to get the multi-index right. Eventually this will need to be done at scale. Also happy to approach in a different way.

The underlying problem is to match locations with all other locations within a given distance. This is done in a separate module and the output is the lists of lists referenced above.

Answer (score 1):

I would construct the index, merge with `original` and `set_index`:

```
ret = (pd.concat(pd.DataFrame({'Org':i, 'Match':v}) for i,v in enumerate(matches))
         .merge(original, left_on='Match', right_index=True, how='left')
         .set_index(['Org','Match'])
      )
```

Output:

```
            ID              City
Org Match                       
0   0      JFK      New York, NY
1   1      EWR        Newark, NJ
    3      PHL  Philadelphia, PA
2   2      BWI     Baltimore, MD
3   1      EWR        Newark, NJ
    3      PHL  Philadelphia, PA
4   4      DCA    Washington, DC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
matches = [[0], [1, 3], [2], [1, 3], [4]]

result = pd.concat([df.iloc[match] for match in matches], keys=list(range(len(matches))), names=['Org', 'Match'])

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
            ID              City
Org Match                       
0   0      JFK      New York, NY
1   1      EWR        Newark, NJ
    3      PHL  Philadelphia, PA
2   2      BWI     Baltimore, MD
3   1      EWR        Newark, NJ
    3      PHL  Philadelphia, PA
4   4      DCA    Washington, DC
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct a series from `matches` and use `explode` to get values to use for `reindex` and `set_index`. Finally, `swaplevel`

```
s = pd.Series(matches).explode()
df = original.reindex(s).set_index(s.index, append=True).swaplevel(1,0)

Out[54]:
      ID              City
0 0  JFK      New York, NY
1 1  EWR        Newark, NJ
  3  PHL  Philadelphia, PA
2 2  BWI     Baltimore, MD
3 1  EWR        Newark, NJ
  3  PHL  Philadelphia, PA
4 4  DCA    Washington, DC
```

---

Or you may construct multiindex and use it to `reindex`, `set_index` and reordering the order of multiindex of the final df

```
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i, y) for i, x in enumerate(matches) for y in x])
df = original.reindex(ix.get_level_values(1)).set_index(ix.get_level_values(0), append=True).swaplevel(1,0) 

Out[43]:
      ID              City
0 0  JFK      New York, NY
1 1  EWR        Newark, NJ
  3  PHL  Philadelphia, PA
2 2  BWI     Baltimore, MD
3 1  EWR        Newark, NJ
  3  PHL  Philadelphia, PA
4 4  DCA    Washington, DC
```